# Super is undefined only in production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I have developed a website using react and when using webpack's command 'webpack --config webpack.dev.js'
it works like charm.

but when using my production config it gives the following exception when going to the website:
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.

can't even see what causes this because it is being thrown from the bundle which is minified.

webpack.common.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:{*an entry object*},
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "*a path*"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [{ loader: 'css-loader' }] },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ttf|otf|woff2|woff)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            }

        ]
    }
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [new WebpackNotifierPlugin(), new BrowserSyncPlugin()]
});
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
});
```

babelrc:

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"], 
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] 
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "an app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
  }
}
```

most of my googling found some uglify library solution which I dont use.

tried many things like setting 'set NODE_ENV=production' before the build.

Im really clueless and nowhere on the internet has the solution for it.

oh and BTW all of my components are functional, I did not inherit from React.Component and used lower case by mistake. (seen this while googling too)

Comment: Have you tried enabling [source maps](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#source-mapping) in production? That might help track down the error in the unminified code

Comment: @Khauri yes I have, still shows the same exception in the chrome console being thrown from the bundle. in development mode it works perfectly.

Comment: @edena did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue in one of my projects, it turns out one of the dependencies was already minified and terser was aggressively minifying it again, this resulted in some component getting empty names and therefore react was complaining about it.

In order to fix this issue I had to update the terser plugin configurations as follow:

```
optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          keep_fnames: false, // <---- By setting this value to false everything started working again
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Setting `keep_fnames` to `false` fixed the problem for my case!